# VSCode Extension Formatter StandardJS - JavaScript Standard Style Sam Chen not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, standardjs

My team uses **StandardJS - JavaScript Standard Style Sam Chen** VSCode extension for code formatting and suggestion in my team. I also have to use that.

I have installed the extension, but when I try to save the code Auto formatter doesn't work the extra spaces and tabs are not removed.

**My settings.json looks like:**

[image: settings.json file]